# Enable or Disable Jquery Datatable Checkbox base of the value of a column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need enable or disable the checkbox in my datatable base of the value of the 'Status' column. I want the checkbox to be disable when the status is "Closed". I know I can stop displaying the close ticket by changing the where clause in my query. but i want to user to be able to see all tickets

Table display

[image]

C# Code

```
 public ActionResult GetChildTickets1(int id)
    {
        _db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        IQueryable<VmRequest> results = _db.VmRequests.Where(i => i.ParentId == id) ;
        return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

JQuery Code

```
 // Datatable value from the database
  var enabletemplateListVM;
    function tchildticket () {
        enabletemplateListVM = {
            dt: null,
            init: function () {
                dt = $('#childtable').DataTable({
                    "pageLength": 10,                                              
                    "ajax": {
                        // Url
                        "url": "/Home/GetChildTickets1?id="+@ViewBag.id,
                        "type": "POST",
                        "datatype": "json",
                        "dataSrc": function (d) {
                            return d
                        }
                    },
                     // Table Columns to display the data
                    "columns": [                            
                   {
                            "targets": [0],
                            "data": "Id", "autoWidth": true,
                            "render": function (data, type, full) {
                                return '<input type="checkbox" id="cticket" name="cticket" value="' + full.Id + '"/>';
                            },
                        },
                        { "title": "Ticket Id", "data": "Id", "name": "Id" },
                        {
                            "title": "Logged On", "data": "CreatedOn", "name": "CreatedOn",
                            // Date Formating
                          render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                                if (data !== null) {
                                    return (moment(data).format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
                                } else {
                                    return '';
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        { "title": "Ticket Type", "data": "TypeofWork", "name": "TypeofWork" },
                        { "title": "Subject", "data": "Subject", "name": "Subject" },
                        { "title": "Contact", "data": "ContactId", "name": "ContactId" },                         
                        { "title": "Status ", "data": "CurrentStatus", "name": "CurrentStatus" },                        
                        { "title": "Team", "data": "Teamid", "name": "Teamid" },
                    ],
                });
            }
        }
        enabletemplateListVM.init();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code below for the column containing checkboxes.

Please note that I assumed closed tickets contain "Closed" in the status column, but change the code accordingly.

```
{
    "data": "Id", 
    "autoWidth": true,
    "render": function (data, type, full) {
        if(type === 'display'){
             var attrDisabled = '';

             // If ticket is closed
             if(full['CurrentStatus'] === 'Closed'){
                // Disable the checkbox
                attrDisabled = 'disabled';
             }

             data = '<input type="checkbox" id="cticket" name="cticket" value="' + full.Id + '" ' + attrDisabled + '/>';
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the complete code is very hard to help you. But if after the datatable is created you use something like:

```
jQuery('table').each(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
});
```

You can get the content of datatable and edit the checkbox visibility.

Comment: I just added the C# Code missing any help from you?